# replacing macro with a function causes "signed/unsigned mismatch" warning

Tags: c++, function, macros, compiler-warnings

For this snippet

```
   const std::vector<int> v;
   if (v.size() != 1) {} // could call operator!=()
```

the code complies cleanly even at high warnings levels (all warnings enabled in Visual Studio 2022).  However, if I pass the arguments to a function

```
   const auto f = [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) { if (lhs != rhs) {}};
   f(v.size(), 1);
```

the compiler generates a **'!=': signed/unsigned mismatch** warning.

How can I make the function behave the same way as the "inline" code, i.e., no warning?

---

Keep in mind that the "real code" is something like

```
#define f(lhs, rhs) if (lhs != rhs) {}
```

**I'd like to "do the 'right thing'" and replace the macro with a function**

```
temmplate<typename TLhs, typename TRhs>
inline void f(TLhs&& lhs, TRhs&& rhs)
{
   if (lhs != rhs) {}
}
```

Comment: `f(v.size(), 1u);` (or `f(v.size(), 1uz);` in C++23)?

Comment: @Jarod42 sure ... but that's not needed when `f` is a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the problem out of your code by calling `std::cmp_not_equal`

```
const auto f = [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
     if (std::cmp_not_equal(lhs, rhs)) { blah blah }
};
```

This family of functions, added in C++20, is [defined in a way that properly compares integer arguments even in the presence of a signed/unsigned mismatch](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.intcmp#lib:cmp_not_equal).

Now the Standard library author is responsible for writing "all that template gunk" and all you need to do extra is `#include <utility>`

---

For the specific case of assertions, you need a macro anyway to capture information.

```
#define ASSERT_EQ(actual, expected) do { \
      if (lhs == rhs) break; \
      log_assertion_failure(__FILE__, __LINE__, #actual, actual, expected); \
  } while(0)
```

Comment: See the macro; `lhs` and `rhs` aren't necessarily integer arguments.  Yes, they cause the warning; but the real objective is to replace the macro with a function.

Comment: @JackBrown: Then provide two versions, named differently, to force review of the consuming code and make sure that a strict inequality is actually appropriate (for non-integer arguments it usually isn't).  Different names aren't a technical necessity, overloading is possible, but unwise when they aren't actually doing interchangeable things.  Is this "macro" something along the lines of `ASSERT_ACTUAL_EQUALS_EXPECTED_VALUE` ?

Comment: @JackBrown: Well, an assert needs to be a macro not because of signed/unsigned comparison warnings, but because you need to capture the location (`__FILE__` and `__LINE__`) and usually you also want to stringize the expression.  These have no equivalent in real functions.

Comment: That's not to say that you can't replace part of the macro with a call to a helper function, and end up with something like `#define ASSERT_EQ(actual, expected) do { if (lhs == rhs) break; log_assertion_failure(__FILE__, __LINE__, #actual, actual, expected); } while(0)`

Comment: Yes, correct; `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` (and the result of `#arg`) can all be passed to a function, making the macro smaller.  I guess it's just not possible to "entirely" replace a macro with a function. ‍♂️

Comment: If you don't need the stringify operator, you could do it without any macro, replacing the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` part with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location.

Comment: @Federico *that's* the whole problem ... as soon as the macro is gone, compiler warnings are triggered.

Answer (score 5):

In the direct comparison the compiler knows the type of both side of the comparison, and can therefore make sure that the `1` will be an unsigned type of the correct size.

When you call your lambda the type for `rhs` will be deduced as an `int`, because that's what `1` really is. And since `lhs` will be an unsigned type, you get the warning in the comparison when you compare the unsigned size with the (signed) `int` value `1`.

---

You will get the same problem with any kind of callable object where the compiler must deduce the arguments, like for example function templates:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void f(T const& lhs, U const& rhs);
```

For a function template the solution is simple: Use the same single type for both arguments:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T const& lhs, T const& rhs);
```

Comment: @JackBrown For a lambda with auto-deducing arguments I don't think it's really possible. (Unless you change the type of the argument value you actually pass, as mentioned by Scheff's Cat below).

Comment: @JackBrown `1u` or `(size_t)1`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so yet another instance where it's not really possible to get rid of a macro?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is a specific case.  So even though you're comparing a signed `int` to an unsigned `std::vector::size_type`, the compiler tell that there's no problem.  It will implicitly convert 1 to the unsigned type, which has no problem representing a 1.

In the second example, you have the general case.  When instantiating the lambda function for the (`size_type`, `int`) case, it has to be prepared for any set of values.  It cannot assume that the value of the `int` can be converted to the `size_type` without altering the value.  (In theory, it could inline the lambda, and then it would see the specific values in this particular invocation, but apparently it doesn't do that.)

The solution is to make the two parameters identical (or, at least, compatible).

```
f(v.size(), 1u);
```

**ETA**:  If you want to make the function specifically for comparing sizes, you could use specific types in the interface.

```cpp
// Assuming `std::vector::size_type` is the same as `std::size_t`...
const auto f = [](std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs) { if (lhs != rhs) {}};
```

Then, when you call `f(v.size(), 1)`, the compiler will convert the `int` to `size_t`, which will avoid the comparison error.

If you want the generality for other cases, you could use a function template, and then specialize it for the (`size_t`, `int`) case by having it explicitly case the `int` to the size type.

Comment: @JackBrown:  I edited my response to try to address that question.

Comment: "If you want the generality for other cases, you could use a function template, and then specialize it ..." so let's see ... a simple "one line" macro or a whole bunch of template gunk? 

Comment: Well, yeah.  The preprocessor's textual substitution was a clever hack, but it doesn't do you any favors when it comes to type checking.  Type checking prevents many bugs and can even enable some optimizations.  C++ introduced templates, lambdas, and other language features to enable the generality of preprocessor tricks without giving up the benefits of type checking, but the cost is more verbose source code.

Comment: A "clever hack" that is one line vs. dozens seems rather useful; it's going to hard to convince real-world programmers to give it up.

Comment: A "whole bunch" of template gunk is not needed.  Specialization is not needed.  As the other answer says, it's as straightforward as deducing both arguments to a common type.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Cool.  I hadn't noticed that addition to the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it applies to your case fully, but you can *"force"* type of one operand:

```
temmplate <typename T>
void f(const T& lhs, const std::struct_identity_t<T>& rhs)
{
   if (lhs != rhs) {/*..*/}
}
```

[std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is C++20, but can be implemented for previous standard.

Comment: That looks a whole lot better than some other suggestions!

Comment: @JackBrown: It's messier than Some programmer dude's final suggestion.  Appropriate if the second argument should be ignored for the purpose of type inference, but if using both is fine, skip the unnecessary `type_identity`.